# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken() does not send to react-native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to avoid weird libraries or overpriced services such as Azure or non-compliant services as Firebase to send notifications to my App. As such I decided to build my own native-module that can do that, but my skills in Swift are still beginning and I am kinda stuck with this:

So basically I am doing this to register for notifications after I get the consent:

```
import UserNotifications

@objc(PushNotificationManager)
class PushNotificationManager: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  
  private var deviceToken: String?
  private var callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock?

  @objc static let shared = PushNotificationManager()
  
  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

@objc func registerForPushNotifications(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      self.callback = callback
    }
  }

@objc func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    self.deviceToken = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print("Device token set: \(String(describing: self.deviceToken))")
    self.callback?([NSNull(), self.deviceToken])
  }

  @objc func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
    self.callback?([error.localizedDescription, NSNull()])
  }
```

And then in react-native this:

```
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            console.log("get permission")
            PushNotificationManager.requestPermission((error, granted) => {
                console.log("step 1")
                console.log(error)
                if (granted) {
                    console.log("step 2")
                    console.log("granted")
                    PushNotificationManager.registerForPushNotifications((error, token) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("step 3")
                            console.log(error)
                        } else {
                            console.log("step 3")
                            console.log(token)
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

However the token or error is never logged. My understanding is that UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications is asynchronous and this returns undefined in React-native due to try to run synchronous but neither with AI or google search was able to fix it.

Any tip?

EDIT:
and AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  self.moduleName = @"medux";
  
  self.initialProps = @{};
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    PushNotificationManager *manager = [PushNotificationManager new]; 
    center.delegate = manager;

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  const unsigned *tokenBytes = (const unsigned *)[deviceToken bytes];
  NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                     ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                     ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                     ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];
  NSLog(@"Device Token: %@", token);

  PushNotificationManager *manager = PushNotificationManager.shared; 
  [manager application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
  PushNotificationManager *manager = PushNotificationManager.shared; 
  [manager application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
```

Comment: How do you establish the singleton instance of `PushnotificationManager` that is in the `shared` property? Have you added the push notification capability to your Xcode project? Are you running in a real device?

Comment: It seems likely that the instance of your notification manager that you are calling from your app delegate isn't the instance that has the `callback` property set.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a line when was copying the example by parts. So basically I initiate the shared, and then use it in the appDelegate to always have the same instance. 

The idea was to when didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken concludes, to associate the token to a variable and pass it inside the callback to the react-native, but, the problem is that last callback is never being sent. Concretely the  self.callback?([NSNull(), self.deviceToken]) never gets transmitted through registerForPushNotifications()

Comment: In `didFinishLaunching` you are creating an instance of your manager and assigning it as the delegate to the notification center, but that instance isn't going to be whatever `PushNotificationManager.shared` is, and also probably isn't the instance that react native is calling to pass the callback to.  You probably need to create a property on your app delegate to hold an instance of your manager and then in the `registerForPushNotifications` function assign `self` to that property

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are ending up with numerous, unrelated instances of `PushNotificationManager`.

I would add a property to your `AppDelegate` to hold an reference to `PushNotificationManager` and then assign `self` to that in `registerForPushNotifications`

```
@objc func registerForPushNotifications(_ callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate;
    self.callback = callback
    AppDelegate.notificationManager = self
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()   
    }
  }
```

Then in your app delegate function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 
  [self.notificationManager application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, edit it. It is difficult to read code from comments. It is also a mistake to assume that the token has any particular format or fixed size. It is an opaque `Data` instance. You could base64 encode the token if you wanted a printable representation.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the post and placed the contents of the AppDelegate.m 

in Xcode I can see the token logged, but it is never returned to React-native as part of the registerForPushNotifications

Comment: you are right, it was multiple instances but not yet solved. kinda have a problem bridging everything correctly to have the shared as a singleton